# JavaFX loading CSS style from resources folder

Tags: css, eclipse, javafx, nullpointerexception, getresource

Project Structure:

[image: Project Structure]

I'm currently developing a JavaFX application in Eclipse and I'm having trouble loading a .css stylesheet from the resources folder.

I've already added the resources folder to the classpath (**Project Properties** -> **Source** -> **Add Folder**)

The following code is being used:

```java
this.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/CSS/application-container.css").toExternalForm());
```

`getResource()` is throwing **NullPointerException** I've read other posts and tried everything but can't seem to get it to work.

**EDIT:** Managed to get it working by deleting and restoring the bin folder. Now the .css is loaded but by some reason it's not being applied, however using the javaFX method `.setStyle(...)` with the same content of the .css, it works.

```
private void buildHeader() {
    this.header.setId("header-container");
    this.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/CSS/application-container.css").toExternalForm());
    // this.header.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #7b9bce;");      this way works
}
```

CSS:

```
@charset"utf-8";

#header-container {
    -fx-background-color: #7b9bce;
}
```

Comment: Check the contents of the build folder to see if the CSS file is in the expected place.

Comment: `this` refer to what here ?

Comment: @James_D the .css file got copied by eclipse in bin/CSS/application-container.css, so it seems that's okay. Don't know why there is no resources folder inside bin though

Comment: @BoHalim this in this context refers to a BorderPane

Comment: There's no resources folder inside bin, because it's a source folder, not a package. That all looks correct. Are you certain that `getClass().getResource("/CSS/application-container.css")` is returning null? (i.e. you're not getting the npe from somewhere else). Try `System.out.println(getClass().getResource(...))` to check.

Comment: @James_D I deleted the bin folder and re-added the resources folder to the build path and now getResource is no longer returning null. The issue I'm having now is that the style is not applying, however `hbox.setStyle(...)` works perfectly fine and renders the style. But I'd really like to use external .css to avoid mixing GUI design with code.

Comment: Can you just show the part of your style that does not apply ? For information, the style applies only in the case of Nodes having a default style class (Controls) example (button/scroll-pane/combo-box...) , if you use their styleClass in your CSS code of course, If a node does not have a default class style, you must use an #style ID or a name you want, and assign it to your node by the `setId()` or `getStyleClass()` method. !

Comment: @Franch [Edit] your question with additional information, instead of posting code in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working with the external .css, apparently *JavaFX CSS parser* **doesn't allow** `@charset "utf-8"` or any @ anotation. It didn't show any warning whatsoever.

Solution:

**Change this:**

```
@charset"utf-8";

#header-container {
    -fx-background-color: #7b9bce;
}
```

***To this:***

```
#header-container {
    -fx-background-color: #7b9bce;
```